# TypeError: init() takes 0 positional arguments but 5 were given

Tags: python, neural-network

I'm coding with python and this message appears as I code live:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-d56dec7d72db> in <module>()
      8 
      9 # create instance of neural network
---> 10 n= neuralNetwork(input_nodes,hidden_nodes,output_nodes,learning_rate)
     11
```

> TypeError: **init**() takes 0 positional arguments but 5 were given

What exactly does it signify and what can I do about it?

Here is my code:

```
#neural network class definition
class neuralNetwork:

#initialise the neural network
def __init__():
    pass

#train the neural network
def train():
    pass
#query the neural network
def query():
    pass

#initialise the neural network
def __init__(self,inputnodes, hiddennodes,outputnodes,learningrate):

# set number of nodes in each input, hidden, output layer
self.inodes= inputnodes
self.hnodes = hiddennodes
self.onodes = outputnodes 

#learning rate
self.lr = learningrate
pass

# number of input, hidden and output nodes
input_nodes = 3
hidden_nodes = 3
output_nodes = 3

# learning rate is 0.3
learning_rate = 0.3

# create instance of neural network 
n= neuralNetwork(input_nodes,hidden_nodes,output_nodes,learning_rate)
```

Comment: Please indent Python code properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 `__init__` methods in your `neuralNetwork` class:
1 `__init__` without any parameters and 1 `__init__` that has 4 parameters.

Are you trying to create multiple/overloaded constructors?
You can't do it like that in Python (unlike in, say, Java or C++).

The error you're getting means the `__init__` without any parameters is being used, so the interpreter does not expect any arguments, but you passed 4 (`(input_nodes, hidden_nodes, output_nodes, learning_rate)`) then +1 for `self`.

Based on how you want to instantiate the class, you have to remove the one that does not accept any arguments.

```
class neuralNetwork:

    # REMOVE THIS EMPTY CONSTRUCTOR
    # initialise the neural network
    # def __init__():
    #    pass

    # initialise the neural network
    def __init__(self,inputnodes, hiddennodes,outputnodes,learningrate):
        # initialization code

    # ... rest of class ...

n = neuralNetwork(input_nodes, hidden_nodes, output_nodes, learning_rate)
```

If you want to have multiple constructors, you can define unique `__init__`'s:

```
class neuralNetwork:

    # initialise a default neural network
    def __init__():
        # default initialization code    

    # initialise a custom neural network
    def init_custom(self,inputnodes, hiddennodes,outputnodes,learningrate):
        # custom initialization code

    # ... rest of class ...

n = neuralNetwork()
n.init_custom(input_nodes, hidden_nodes, output_nodes, learning_rate)
```

Or try the other methods already described in other posts:

- [What is a clean, pythonic way to have multiple constructors in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/682504/2745495)
- [Can I have two init functions in a python class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3134829/2745495)
- [How to overload **init** method based on argument type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/141545/2745495)